# Applescript to change osx desktop (spaces) not working

Tags: macos, applescript

I am running osx Sierra, 10.12.4

The following applescript used to trigger a switch to the next desktop space to the right.

`tell application "System Events"
    key code 124 using control down
end tell`

I can verify that "System Events" is working and will trigger other keyboard commands that affect system processes such as:

`tell application "System Events"
    key code 28 using {control down, command down, option down}
end tell`

...which will trigger the accessibility setting that turns the screen to inverse colors.

Does anybody have a solution for restoring this functionality in Sierra?

Comment: Is the shortcut enabled in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Mission Control?

Comment: Very strange. I can get it to work by manually pressing the shortcut but I cannot get it to work with AppleScript

Comment: @vadian yes, and the keyboard shortcut was working. I implemented the suggestion in the accepted answer, and changed the keys to (9, 0) for (left, right)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed the shortcut for move right in system preferences/Keyboard/Shortcuts/Mission control.. from ctrl + right arrow to ctrl + 0 (key code 29 using (control down)) and it works now.

[image]

```
tell application "System Events"
    key code 29 using (control down)
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!